# Find the crop parameters from two images

Tags: python, image-processing

Given two images - one a cropped (but not scaled) portion of the other, how can I find the crop parameters (i.e.: the x and y offsets and width/height)? The idea is to crop one image (screenshot) by hand, and then crop a lot more at the same points.

Ideally via imagemagick, but I am happy with any pseudo-code solution, or with Perl, Python, JavaScript (in order of preference)

I have thought of a brute-force approach (find the first pixel which is the same color, check the next, keep going until different, or move to the next). Before I go down this barabarous (and probably slow) route, I'd like to check for better ones.

Comment: See ImageMagick compare method.  https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/ and https://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template matching can be used for the identification of smaller image within a larger image.

The following resource might be helpful. Please check it out

https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Comment: Neat! fast, and a good excuse to start using OpenCV

Comment: @simone beware you might fall in love with it :p